# How to transpose rows to columns in SQL SERVER without creating staging table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot-table, transpose

Please help me to transpose the below table, without creating a staging table. Tried PIVOT but failed. Any suggestions will also be helpful. Thanks!

**Existing table:**

| TIME | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 4/8/2020 5:18 | 1 |
| 4/8/2020 5:22 | 0 |
| 4/8/2020 7:22 | 1 |
| 4/8/2020 7:31 | 0 |
| 4/9/2020 1:44 | 1 |
| 4/9/2020 1:50 | 0 |

**Desired results:**

| 1 | 0 |
| --- | --- |
| 4/8/2020 5:18 | 4/8/2020 5:22 |
| 4/8/2020 7:22 | 4/8/2020 7:31 |
| 4/9/2020 1:44 | 4/9/2020 1:50 |

Comment: How did PIVOT "fail"?  I'd suggest you do some more research and try [PIVOT](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-pivot/) again.  This is definitely what you're looking to do.

Comment: Any suggestion or links to refer? please share

Comment: Yes, I already included one link in my original comment as a starting point.

Comment: PIVOT is failing because the aggregate function MAX() or MIN() on the time columns is returning only 1 row from the expected result. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'd suggest trying the answer from Gordon Linoff below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution in combination `ROW_NUMBER` window function and `PIVOT`:

```
SELECT [0], [1]
FROM 
(
  SELECT Value, TIME, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Value ORDER BY TIME) Rb
  FROM MyTable
) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
  MAX(TIME)
  FOR Value IN ([0], [1])
) AS PivotTable
```

Answer (score 1):

You can enumerate them and aggregate:

```
select max(case when value = 1 then time end) as value_1,
       max(case when value = 0 then time end) as value_0
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by value order by time) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by seqnum;
```

Comment: Thanks! It works too. But can't mark both answers as solved.

Comment: @MamunurRashid . . . This was 16 minutes before the other answer.